# Hex to Decimal to a specific JSON format

Tags: python, json

I am trying to create a python script that reads a hex txt file, writes to decimal in txt, then reads the decimal file and writes, in a specific format, to JSON. Here is an example of the three files.

Initial hex txt:

```
(ABC 01) Part: 1
00, 0a, 00, 0c

(ABC 01) Part: 2
02, fd, 01, 5e

(ABC 01) Part: 3


(ABC 05) Part: 4
00, 0a, 00, 0c
```

Here is the decimal txt file that is outputted:

```
(ABC 01) Part: 1
0, 10, 0, 12
(ABC 01) Part: 2
2, 253, 1, 64
(ABC 01) Part: 3
(ABC 05) Part: 4
0, 10, 0, 12
```

The JSON file that is supposed to be outputted from the decimal file:

```
[{"ABC": 01, "Section": "1", "Data": [0, 0, 10, 228]},
{"ABC": 01, "Section": "2", "Data": [2, 6, 253, 88]},
{"ABC": 01, "Section": "3", "Data": []},
{"ABC": 01, "Section": "2", "Data": [0, 10, 0, 12]}]
```

This is optional but I got rid of the spacing in the decimal file after converting the hex file because I was getting weird formatting when going from decimal to JSON, so I was wondering if I could keep the spacing in the decimal file while having the specific JSON format

Here is my current code:

```
import os
import json


#def getNewTxts(path):    
for file_name in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    try:
        if file_name.endswith('.txt'):  # Pass on different File Extension as Arguments, if File Extension gets changed in future
            print("Found txt:", file_name)  
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('Could not find the text file!')


def hex_to_decimal(hex_str):
    try:
        return str(int(hex_str, 16))
    except ValueError:
        return hex_str

hex_input_file = 'hex.txt'
decimal_output_file = 'decimal.txt'
json_output_file = 'decimalJSONFormat.json'


# Convert hex to decimal and save in a file
try:
    with open(hex_input_file, 'r') as infile, open(decimal_output_file, 'w') as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            hex_values = line.strip().split(',')  # Split line into hex values
            decimal_values = [hex_to_decimal(hex_val) for hex_val in hex_values]
            decimal_line = ', '.join(decimal_values) + '\n'  # Join decimal values with ', ' and add newline
            if any(val.strip() for val in decimal_values):  # Check if any non-empty value exists in the line
                outfile.write(decimal_line)
    print(f"Conversion to decimal complete. Output saved to {decimal_output_file}")

    # Convert decimal to JSON
    with open(decimal_output_file, 'r') as decimal_file, open(json_output_file, 'w') as json_file:
        data = [line.strip() for line in decimal_file if line.strip()]  # Read lines and split values
        json.dump(data, json_file, indent=2)
    print(f"Conversion to JSON complete. Output saved to {json_output_file}")


except FileNotFoundError:
    print("Input file(s) not found.")
```

This is the actual JSON output:

```
[

"(ABC 01) Part: 1"

"0, 10, 0, 12"

"(ABC 01) Part: 2"

"2, 253, 1, 64"

"(ABC 01) Part: 3"

"(ABC 05) Part: 6"

"0, 10, 0, 12"

]
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution can be using `re` module to parse the text from the file:

```py
import json
import re

text = """\
(ABC 01) Part: 1
00, 0a, 00, 0c

(ABC 01) Part: 2
02, fd, 01, 5e

(ABC 01) Part: 3

(ABC 05) Part: 4
00, 0a, 00, 0c"""

pat_groups = r"^\((\S+) (\d+)\) Part: (\d+)\s*(.*?)(?=^\(|\Z)"
pat_hex = r"[\da-fA-F]+"

data = []
for name, n, section, group in re.findall(pat_groups, text, flags=re.S | re.M):
    data.append(
        {
            name: int(n),
            "Section": section,
            "Data": list(map(lambda i: int(i, 16), re.findall(pat_hex, group))),
        }
    )

json_string = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
print(json_string)
```

Prints:

```json
[
    {
        "ABC": 1,
        "Section": "1",
        "Data": [
            0,
            10,
            0,
            12
        ]
    },
    {
        "ABC": 1,
        "Section": "2",
        "Data": [
            2,
            253,
            1,
            94
        ]
    },
    {
        "ABC": 1,
        "Section": "3",
        "Data": []
    },
    {
        "ABC": 5,
        "Section": "4",
        "Data": [
            0,
            10,
            0,
            12
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Is it possible to have "ABC", "Section", and "Data" along with the brackets in one line similar to how it is in the question?

Comment: @CzarTou Python `json` module doesn't have this functionality - but it doesn't matter, the output is valid Json anyway.